# What caused the NullReferenceException in WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes ()?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception

I am trying to track down a problem that only happens in release mode and is most likely caused by the invalid obfuscation of some property. I know it happens when initializing a specific control but this control is huge. I have spent a day going through all the XAML and Bindings and still can't see what is causing this exception.

**Is there any way to get more information. To know what caused this exception?**

```
Exception : System.NullReferenceException
Message   : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source    : PresentationFramework
Help      : 
Stack     :
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at MyClass.InitializeComponent()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not seem possible to get a more detailed exception message. Dividing the problematic XAML into smaller parts is the way to go.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know a way to get a more detailed exception message, but it might at least be useful to other people to know possible causes. I've just tracked a `NullReferenceException` in `WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes` down to a `DependencyProperty` which was registered with `DependencyProperty.Register(string, Type, Type)`. Changing

```csharp
public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Foo), typeof(object), typeof(Bar));
```

to

```csharp
public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Foo), typeof(object), typeof(Bar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: How in the world did you manage to discover that?!  You da man.  I've been fighting this problem for months without a clue as to the cause.

Comment: @Pat, I can't remember how I discovered it, but I'm glad it helped you.